# XML File Changes using Installshield2011

Tags: installshield

I am developing an add-on installer using Installshield 2011 and project type is Basic MSI. I got a requirement where i need to update app.config file; the mentioned app.config is not part of current installer; app.config will be available by installing the base product. And on top of this my add-on installer will update the app.config file.

I am using XML File Changes feature provided by Installshield, i have configured it in the following steps:

1. Import the updated app.config file under XML File changes view.
2. Create a new element and assign key and value to it.
3. Repeated 1 and 2 and added 7 to 8 new entries as per the requirement

During testing i am seeing that the app.config file has been updated but entries are in single line instead of one below the other. I cannot enable "**Format XML after changes**" because one of the service which is referenced to app.config is not working and when i revoke the option services runs perfectly.

Is there any workaround/option to tell/ask installshield insert xml tag one below the other not in sinlge line using XML File Changes?

Thanks,
Chetan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If XML Changes isn't formatting the document in a way that's acceptable, you could consider using the Text File Changes which is just a simpler search and replace without understanding the schema of XML.  Otherwise options are to check out Windows Installer XML ( you can use the XmlConfig elements found in the Util extension in a merge module and then use that merge module in InstallShield )  or to just write your own custom actions.